# Obfuscating the message part of a message center subscribe using Xamarin. Is good?

Tags: security, xamarin, token, message, obfuscation

I would like to manually obfuscate the message part "message" to a token like "©". I want to hide the intent of the message and hinder (make it harder for) hackers (and hacking tools) from seeing the message. Would this be beneficial in making it harder to hack or otherwise read (while at rest or in transit)? I would use a remark statement to show a more descriptive name/intent.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<myObject>(this, "message", async 
(sender) => 
{
  //Do work
});
```

To...

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<myObject>(this, "©", async    //"©" = blah blah
(sender) => 
{
  //Do work
});
```

Comment: SecureString? https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Security.SecureString/

Comment: The question is meant to ask if this obfuscation shown is beneficial. SecureString may be an improvement. Would this obfuscation make it harder to hack? Is the question.

Comment: One day and 25 views later: Does anyone have any comments? Thoughts? Would you agree that replacing a descriptive string with a token symbol obviously hides the intent of the string? With that said if a hacker saw the token in code at rest or sent via a message wouldn't it be harder to work with. At rest the token symbol would appear with other symbols in a hex editor or other spy type tools. It would be obfuscated/ disguised. Comments?

Comment: Interesting still no comments after 32 views lol